# How to access the global-level object from a callback inside the same global-level object's attribute?

Tags: javascript, events, callback, this

```
var calendar = {
  activeDates: null,

  dateClicked: function () {
    this.activeDates = document.querySelectorAll(
      '[data-calendar-status="active"]'
    )
    for (var i = 0; i < this.activeDates.length; i++) {
      this.activeDates[i].addEventListener('click', this.eventListener)
    }
  },

  eventListener: function () {
    this.removeSelectedClass()
    this.classList.add('vcal-date--selected')
  },

  removeSelectedClass: function () {
    // details omitted
  },

  dateChecked: function () {
    //will call removeEventListener here
  }
}
```

I want to call the function `removeSelectedClass()` in the event listener callback `eventListener`, and I know for sure `this.removeSelectedClass()` is wrong as this `this` refers to the context object `this.activeDates[i]` instead of `calendar`. A simple solution involves creating an anonymous function for the event listener callback but it is not possible in this case because I want to reuse `eventListener` in `dateChecked`. What should I do?

Comment: Can you show the code that gives your context? There is no answer unless you show how you use your object.

Comment: @GetSet - That's shown in `eventListener` above: `this.removeSelectedClass()` (which the OP says, correctly, they know isn't right).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The methods in `calendar` *close over* the `calendar` variable, so you can just use `calendar.removeSelectedClass()`:

```
    eventListener: function () {
      calendar.removeSelectedClass()
//    ^^^^^^^^
      this.classList.add('vcal-date--selected')
    },
```

In the more general case, if these are DOM event listeners, you could use the [usual `this` solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-context-inside-a-callback) so that `this` within `eventListener` is `calendar`, accept the `event` parameter to `eventListener`, and use [`event.currentTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/currentTarget) to refer to the element when adding the class list (`event.currentTarget.classList.add(...)`). By default, `event.currentTarget` is the same as `this` (it's the element you hooked the event on). But you don't need to do that here since `calendar` is a singleton and `eventListener` has access to it.

Comment: @GetSet - The code the OP's shown is just fine, it shows all the relevant functions and the one function calling the other.

Comment: Im afraid I disagree.I see a class/object declaration pattern on `calendar`. I cant assume what OP does what this.

Comment: Thanks! simply `calendar.removeSelectedClass()` works!

Comment: @GetSet gotcha!